# Translating a passage of a paper by L. Bérard Bergery

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, translation-request, mathematical-french

I am currently studying the following paper on Einstein manifolds:

> L. Bérard Bergery, *Sur de nouvelles variétés riemanniennes d'Einstein*, Inst. Elie Cartan, Univ. Nancy №6, 1-60 (1983).

I have doubts that my translation of the following sentence is correct. Also the quality of my copy is poor unfortunately, at two points I have to guess the wording and this is particularly difficult since I don't speak French.

Here we go:

> La fibration naturelle $G/K \to G/H$ est donc ici le fibré en sphère d'un fibré vectoriel sur $G/H$, de groupe structural H..(letters missing) G-invariant.

My translation:

> The natural fibration $G/K \to G/H$ is therefore the fibration into spheres of a vector bundle over $G/H$, with structure group $H$ which is $G$-invariant.

In case this is difficult to judge I can provide more context.

Below is an image of the page in question:
[image]

Comment: "fibration into spheres of" should be "sphere bundle of". That's all I can say given the information you provided...

Comment: It would probably help to have the name of the article, and, if possible, a scan of the portion you are having difficulty translating.

Comment: The natural fibration $G/K$->$G/H$ is therefore, $ \textbf{in this case} $, the fibration into spheres of a vector bundle over $G/H$ with structure group $H$...$G$-invariant

Comment: @ArthurFischer I have added a scan of the section and I also added the title to the post.

Comment: @harlekin: Thanks.  This will make it easier if someone has access to a (possibly better) copy of the same paper, or if there are contextual issues with the translation that are easier resolved having access to some more information about the paper itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it means the following.

The natural fibration $G/K \to G/H$ is therefore the sphere bundle associated to a vector bundle over $G/H$ (I think he means the unit sphere bundle associated to a vector bundle with an inner product, but I don't have access to the paper), with structure group $H$, which is $G$-invariant.

I am fluent in French, so I tried to translate the meaning as much as I could, except that, as you say, some words are not clear in your copy.